# Can't drop temp table SQL

Tags: sql

Hi Im creating a Temp table and inserting data to the Table. Im going to use the Temp table to Join it to the specific User.

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTempTable
(
    UsersId int,
    ValautionCount int 
)

    SELECT
        U.UserId, 
        COUNT(*) AS ValautionCount
    INTO  #MyTempTable
    FROM 
        Users U
        Right JOIN Valuation V ON V.ValuationUser = U.UserId
    GROUP BY 
        U.UserId



DROP TABLE #MyTempTable
```

When I run this query I get this error : There is already an object named '#Temp' in the database.

But when I run this query `DROP TABLE #MyTempTable` I get this error: Cannot drop the table '#Temp', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
Im using SQL 2012

Comment: Duplicate question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642111/drop-table-fails-for-temp-table

Comment: @Sandeep the answer suggests that the tempTable is created incorrectly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SELECT ... INTO ... statement itself create the #Temp table. Does not need CREATE TABLE statement here. Remove "CREATE TABLE" statement and try.

Answer (score 2):

You already have an entity by name "Temp" in your database. And you are not able to drop that entity because of access permissions.

Comment: I still get the error even if I change the temp table to #MyTempTable. Updated in post

Answer (score 2):

No need to drop the temp table since it visible at only till the session.

```
Create PROCEDURE proctemptable
BEGIN

IF object_id('tempdb..#Temp') is not null  // Try this hope this will work
BEGIN
  DROP TABLE #Temp
END

CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    UsersId int,
    ValautionCount int 
)

SELECT
    U.UserId, 
    COUNT(*) AS ValautionCount
INTO  #Temp
FROM 
    Users U
    Right JOIN Valuation V ON V.ValuationUser = U.UserId
GROUP BY 
    U.UserId

//DROP TABLE #Temp 

END
```

No need to drop the #Temp table, it will drop it automatically when the stored procedure execution completed

OR

Please refer this link for more temp tables in sql server

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/temporary-tables-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

You may be creating the same table twice in your code.

I experienced the same problem, I had copied a section of code I wanted to reuse (modified) into the same procedure, including a `CREATE TABLE` statement - I was effectively creating the table *twice* - and even though the `CREATE TABLE` statements were between separate `BEGIN` and `END` markers, and there was a `DROP TABLE` statement dropping the 1st 'instance' before the 2nd `CREATE` statement, I encountered this exact error.

Comment: The accepted answer explains exactly why the error is happening. Your answer does not add anything useful to it.

Answer (score 0):

Official answer from [Microsoft page on how to drop temp table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) helped me.
In short I used this and it worked fine.

```
use tempdb
go

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#yourtemptable', N'U') IS NOT NULL   
DROP TABLE #yourtemptable;  
GO
```

Using MS SQL 2017